# Python: Range count: On possible uses of range count method

Tags: python, count, range

Can range count method produce a value other than 1(0). And if it cannot then what is the possible use of it if one can use in operator for the same purpose True for 1 and 0 for False.I just try to understand whether this count method is completely avoidable or there are some cases you cannot do without it.Range class without count method ? What would be the probable loss ?

```
>>> r = range(10)
>>> r.count(5) #1
1
>>> r.count(11) #0
>>> 5 in r
True
>>> 11 in r
False
```

> > > range(1,10).count(True)#1..WHAT? HOW ? WHY ? WHY NOT 9 ?

Comment: 1/0 are True/False, I think

Comment: `range` objects are sequences, hence, they implement the sequence methods... but yes, by their nature, the result will always be 0 or 1 (unless you implement some type of object with wacky semantics)

Comment: "range(1,10).count(True)#1..WHAT? HOW ? WHY ? WHY NOT 9 ?" because ``True == 1``.

Comment: isn't 2 True ? bool(2) is True

Comment: ``bool(2)`` is True. That is not the same as ``2`` being True.

Answer (score 2):

The `range.count` method comes from `range` being a [sequence](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq). The point is not that getting the `count` in a range is useful, but getting the `count` in a *sequence* is.

By offering the sequence interface, `range` can be safely used by any operation that expects a sequence.

```py
>>> def head_count(seq):
...     return seq.count(seq[0])
...
>>> head_count([16, 1, 2, 18, 0, 16, -3, 4, 16])
3
>>> head_count(range(15))
1
```

While it is not a common use-case, `sequence.count` can in fact produce values greater than 1 even for sequences of unique elements. This is reflected by `range` as well:

```py
>>> class EQ:
...     """Type that is equal with everything"""
...     def __eq__(self, other):
...         return True
...
>>> r = range(15)
>>> r.count(EQ())
15
>>> EQ() in r  # different meaning than range.count
True
```

---

Historically, `range` was a function that builds a *list* of numbers in Python2. As such, it always provided a sequence.

Turning `range` into a lazy sequence in Python3 was an optimisation as part of [removing many list-producing functions](https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#views-and-iterators-instead-of-lists), since in many usecases no list is actually needed. However, [`range` only partially supporting the sequence interface in the beginning led to several usability issues](https://bugs.python.org/issue9213). As such, the entire sequence interface was added to it for simplicity.

Comment: could we do without count method (as a range method) ?

Comment: @AgaQul Well, yes, but then it would not be a sequence anymore.

Comment: Does it have to be a sequence I feel tempted to ask

Comment: @AgaQul It doesn't have to be anything, but that would make it less useful.